# An objects Id. Call it "id" or call it "classnameId"?

Tags: php, oop

For example, if I have a `User` class and an `Order` class which is the best way to name their ID's?

```
userId vs id
orderId vs id
```

and the same goes for every object with an id.

One of my classes is called `DeliveryRequest` so I have to call it `deliveryRequestId` and as you can see it gets a little bit long and the `getDeliveryRequestId()` and `setDeliveryRequestId()` methods make it even longer and it would be very simple and easier to read if I just have `getId()` and `setId()`.

I am just thinking if you have many classes all with their primary key just called "id" is it bad? Can you/have you run into any problems or confusion when coding and doing database work by shortening the main identifier?

Is there a right or wrong answer or is it just a matter of personal preference?

Thanks.

Comment: Best way in which sense? Why do those classes have an ID anyway?

Comment: For a readability point of view and what is most commonly used when creating classes. It needs an ID so I can update the status of the delivery request and a few other similar operations.

Comment: Are these object always comming from the database? And is the primary key always named `id` in the database tables as well?

Comment: Yeah they are database persistent. That is another thing I forgot to ask, should I rename all my tables primary keys to just ID?

Comment: That's a good question. I would clarify that question first. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/114728/why-is-naming-a-tables-primary-key-column-id-considered-bad-practice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about when you will use the class.

Consider the following:

```
$deliveryRequest->getDeliveryRequestId();
```

vs.

```
$deliveryRequest->getId();
```

I recommend not duplicating the name of the class.

Comment: The top one does look unnecessarily long. I think I am going to just stick to ID from now on. It looks much easier on the eye and like @hek2mgl said less writing which is good.

Answer (score 0):

Thats a good question (I think) because it is a bad naming practice that is often seen. I would name then in any case 'id' instead of 'somethingId'

You can just compare the code:

```
$user = new User();

// looks .. hmmm
$id = $user->getUserId();

// looks much better :)
$id = $user->getId();
```

Comment: @David Yes for readability, and for less writing :) (programmers are lazy ) .. Also I would not ask you : 'What is your person-name?' ... I would just ask: 'What is your name?'